# Event Pass element source with short syntax

Tags: caliburn.micro

This Method worked button event passed TreeView element to ViewModel but short syntax event not passed, Where is the problem? Thanks.

```
<Button Content="Search in TreeView" Height="34" Width="100">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
            <cal:ActionMessage MethodName="SearchTreeView">
                <cal:Parameter Value="{Binding ElementName=TreeView}" />
            </cal:ActionMessage>
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</Button>
<TreeView x:Name="TreeView" ItemsSource="{Binding TreeViewSource}"/>
```

Short syntax event

```
<Button x:Name="SearchTreeView" Content="Search in TreeView" cal:Message.Attach="[Event Click] = [Action SearchTreeView($source.TreeView)]" />

<TreeView x:Name="TreeView" ItemsSource="{Binding TreeViewSource}"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to specify $source.Treeview, just the name of the element, `TreeView` is enough

```
<Button x:Name="SearchTreeView" Content="Search in TreeView" cal:Message.Attach="[Event Click] = [Action SearchTreeView(TreeView)]" />

<TreeView x:Name="TreeView" ItemsSource="{Binding TreeViewSource}"/>
```

That said, it's NOT a good idea to pass a control to the ViewModel. If you want to do something with the the selected item, you should bind TreeView's SelectedItem property to a property on your ViewModel and access this from your SearchTreeView method, eg

```
<Button x:Name="SearchTreeView" Content="Search in TreeView" cal:Message.Attach="[Event Click] = [Action SearchTreeView()]" />

<TreeView x:Name="TreeView" ItemsSource="{Binding TreeViewSource}" SelectedItem={Binding MySelectedItem}"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, This your method not access TreeView ItemsSource and exeption error.         public void SearchTreeView(object sender)
        {
            IEnumerable itemsSource = (sender as TreeView).ItemsSource;}

Comment: `sender`???? Caliburn.Micro actions are NOT events. The value you pass is just data, it should never be a control. Why would you want to access the TreeView.ItemSource from the ViewModel, when the ViewModel ITSELF provides the values for this in its TreeViewSource property?

Comment: I'm using telerik TreeView should by access ExpandAll, CollapseAll methods or GetItemByPath for searching in TreeView.

Comment: You really need to get acquainted with MVVM and Caliburn. The ViewModel is NOT a replacement for the codebehind file and actions are NOT events. You should never pass or reference UI controls in the ViewModel, try to handle their events or do anything related to the UI in general. You really are trying to put your code in the wrong place.